# Is it possible to make .htaccess to connect to DB via PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to read something from a database with PHP and transfer it to the .htaccess file like to read $url and then make the file goes on .htaccess and add the $url that its givven into the database...

Comment: What? Are you asking about routing?

Comment: give us more details. what is user requested url? what is .htaccess resulting rule? what is an imaginated php code for .htaccess? generally answer for your question is NO. but maybe there is another solution that can resolve your problem :-)

Comment: I want to change the url from a php file that auto creating urls from a db...I want to change the urls from db too url like view.php?id=1 to /$title/$id and view.php?id=2 to /$title/$id I know how to Rewrite it in htaccess but I want to auto create url from db

Comment: check my answer, if any questions - you are very welcome

Comment: Theoretically, yes, that is possible. You can use fwrite() to append data to the .htaccess file. In practice, this is a very stupid thing to do, since you can manually create rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. What are you asking for is called routing and is achieved with pure PHP. You only need .htacces to redirect all url calls to single php file from where you can parse the route.

You can read more here http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/

Answer (score -1):

check the @shaddy answer.

that is the way you should move to.

you are mixing things in your mind :-).
try to rethink your application structure this way:

```
1. user types in browser whatever he wants 

2. htaccess must redirect any uri to your unique script, let say index.php 

3. in that index.php you do whatever YOU want, call database, prepare vars, set conditions, 

and CALL OTHER scripts depending on your conditions. that is an idea of routing :-)
```

and google 'routing php examples' :-)